# Why my hook state doesn´t update correctly?

Tags: arrays, reactjs, react-hooks, state

i don't know how make this guys, i can't update my state with the api array, and if i put it in useEffect i have an error cause i am not sending any data, help me please is my first time using stackoverflow

```
    import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
    import getTeam from "../Helpers/getTeam";
    
    const selectTeams = [
        "Barcelona",
        "Real Madrid",
        "Juventus",
        "Milan",
        "Liverpool",
        "Arsenal",
    ];
    
    const Select = () => {
        const [team, setTeam] = useState(null);
        const [loading, setLoading] = useState(null);
    
        const handleOption = async (e) => {
            setLoading(true);
            let teamsJson = await getTeam(e.target.value);
            let arr = [];
            Object.keys(teamsJson).map((teamjs, i) => {
                return arr.push(teamsJson[teamjs]);
            });
            console.log(arr);
            console.log(team);
            setTeam(arr);
            setLoading(false);
        };
    
        return (
            <div
                style={{ background: "skyblue", textAlign: "center", padding: "20px" }}
            >
                <h1>Equipos Disponibles</h1>
                <div>
                    <select onChange={handleOption}>
                        <option>Elige tu equipo</option>
                        {selectTeams.map((selectTeam, i) => {
                            return <option key={i}>{selectTeam}</option>;
                        })}
                    </select>
                </div>
                {loading ? <h1>suave</h1> : (
                    team !== null ? (
                        team.map((newTeam, i) => {
                            return (
                                <div>
                                    the items are here
                                </div>
                            )
                        })
                    ) : null
                )}
            </div>
        );
    };
    
    export default Select;
```

i let you my api file down

```
const getTeam = async (teamName) => {
    const url = `https://www.thesportsdb.com/api/v1/json/1/searchteams.php?t=${teamName}`;

    const res = await fetch(url);

    const team = await res.json();

    return team;
};

export default getTeam;
```

i wanna update my const team with the response of my api call, but it doesn't update it, i dont know what do, please help me

Comment: Are you basically trying to store `Object.values(teamsJson)` into `team` state? How are you verifying/validating that `team` isn't updating?

Comment: With console logs and i'm trying to map the team state to show the info of the api, using conditionals and all that, but i can't, i don't know what can be

Comment: You log `team` *before* you update state. Other than that you make no other references to it in the snippet. Where are you trying to map `team` state? Can you please provide a full code example?

Comment: return (
  <div
   style={{ background: "skyblue", textAlign: "center", padding: "20px" }}
  >
   <h1>Equipos Disponibles</h1>
   <div>
    <select onChange={handleOption}>
     <option>Elige tu equipo</option>
     {selectTeams.map((selectTeam, i) => {
      return <option key={i}>{selectTeam}</option>;
     })}
    </select>
   </div>
   {loading ? <h1>suave</h1> : (
    team !== null ? (
     team.map((newTeam, i) => {
      return (
       <div>
        the items are here
       </div>
      )
     })
    ) : null
   )}
  </div>
 );

Comment: it's already updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `teamsJson` value is an object with a single key and value of some array

```
{ teams: [...] }
```

So you are updating your state with a nested array when you push the value into another array.

```
let arr = [];
Object.keys(teamsJson).map((teamjs, i) => {
  return arr.push(teamsJson[teamjs]);
});
```

Based upon how you want to map your `team` state array I assume you just want the raw inner array from `teamJson`.

```
const { teams } = await getTeam(e.target.value);
setTeam(teams);
```

Then when you are mapping you can access any of the properties you need.

```
team.map((newTeam, i) => {
  return <div key={i}>{newTeam.idTeam}</div>;
})
```

[image: Edit why-my-hook-state-doesn%C2%B4t-update-correctly]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've just tested it & it seems to works just fine.

The only 2 issues seem to be that:

1. You don't use `team` anywhere (apart from a `console.log` statement).
2. At the moment when you `console.log(team);` the constant `team` will (yet) be `null` for the first time (because it still keeps the initial state).

Here's what I see in [React dev tools](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/react-developer-tools/fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi?hl=en) after picking a random team in the `<select>`:

[image]

Comment: I wanna map the state to show the api info, but i cant do it, i use conditionals to do it, but it doesn't work

Comment: @Alvaro hey! Then, please, share the code that shows what you tried in regard to outputting the state. There might be some problem with the code, but we will not be able to help without seeing it.

Comment: return (
  <div
   style={{ background: "skyblue", textAlign: "center", padding: "20px" }}
  >
   <h1>Equipos Disponibles</h1>
   <div>
    <select onChange={handleOption}>
     <option>Elige tu equipo</option>
     {selectTeams.map((selectTeam, i) => {
      return <option key={i}>{selectTeam}</option>;
     })}
    </select>
   </div>
   {loading ? <h1>suave</h1> : (
    team !== null ? (
     team.map((newTeam, i) => {
      return (
       <div>
        the items are here
       </div>
      )
     })
    ) : null
   )}
  </div>
 );